# Disable BasicAuth on specific sub paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I know there are some question on stackoverflow, but nothing helped...

```
http
            .addFilterBefore(RestConfiguration.getCorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("API")
            .antMatchers("/api/confirm/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/version").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and() //HTTP basic Authentication only for API
            .antMatcher("/api/**").httpBasic()
            .and() // angularjs requires csrf
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable();
```

I've a api path with some sub paths. But I want to access two of them without basic auth (`confirm/**` and `version`).

How can I do that? I always get the login dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("API")` rule after `/api/confirm/**` and `/api/version`. Current ordering is not quite right:

```
.antMatchers("/api/confirm/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/version").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("API")
```

To sum up, if you want to only secure `/api/*` and let public access on `/api/confirm/**`, `/api/version` and all other paths without `api` prefix, you should have a `HttpSecurity` config like this:

```
http
        // Same as before
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/confirm/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/version").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("API")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        // Same as before
```

Comment: but then I have the httpBasic also on other paths right..?

Comment: You can exclude them using `permitAll`